# cakePHP, model relations - hasOne, how to update both tables?

Tags: cakephp, relationships

I have two tables: `answers{..., question_id}` and `questions{..., answer_id}`.
In the models I set the `$hasOne` variable to connect the models: `Answers: $hasOne = 'Question'` and `Question: $hasOne = 'Answers'`
There are two views: `answers->add` and `questions->add`, for each question there is only one answer.
Now, I want these tables to be connected, so when a user create a question it will automatically create an answer (tho empty).
I know it's a lot.. But, How it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect answer, here...

http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo